# OCamlにCのような行コメントはないのでしょうか。

Tags: ocaml

Cなどでは // 以降、行の終わりまでがコメントと見なされますが
OCamlにはこのような終端記号の不要な行コメントはないのでしょうか。
ない場合、なぜないのか、自分で定義するにはどうすればよいかについても
教えていただけると幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OCaml に行コメントは無いです。

行コメントの実装は簡単です。ですがどのような記号を採用しても後方互換性を捨てる変更になりますので、今さら採用するほどのものではないと思われているようです。

自分で定義する、というか行コメントを実現するには、

- OCaml 処理系のパーサーを改造する。たとえば、 https://github.com/camlspotter/ocaml/tree/linecomment
- 行コメントを理解してその部分を捨てたコードに変換するプリプロセッサを書いて、OCaml コンパイラの `-pp` オプションにそのプリプロセッサを指定する

という方法があります。後者のほうが浸入的でない改造なので受け入れられやすいと思われます。